# Customise Geany Terminal Color

Tags: terminal, geany

Is there a way to to customise the `Terminal` Color in Geany beyond what's offered in the program itself i.e. a configuration file or something like that.

There is a lot of results for the Editor color but this is about the `Terminal`! I find the default for directories hard to read and in Geany itself you can only change the foreground and background colors.

EDIT: To clarify I want to change the color used for directory names which is currently a dark shade of blue.

Comment: What exactly you want to customize beyond fore/back ground colors?

Answer (score 1):

right click on the Terminal part then select preferences then background colour

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrHSt.png]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately I already know how to change the Background and Foreground colour it's the other colours I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

In your home directory is a file .dir_colors. This file determines among other the Geany VTE colors. Backup your original file if it exists.

To create the file, run this command in your terminal:

```
dircolors --print-database > ~/.dir_colors
```

Read the comments in the file and customize to your liking. Hope this helps!!